# Compatible SQL to test for not null and not empty strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to have compatible SQL for both Oracle database and Microsoft SQL server.

I want a compatible SQL expression that will return true for not null and not empty strings.

If I use:

```
column <> ''
```

it will work on Microsoft SQL server but not on Oracle database (as '' is null for Oracle)

If I use:

```
len(column) > 0
```

it will work on Microsoft SQL server but not on Oracle database (since it uses length() )

Comment: So, even though `''` is `null` in Oracle, I still cannot see why `column <> ''` will not work. If `column` has a (non-empty) value, the condition *will* return `true`, which is what you want. What am I missing? Moreover, if `column` is empty, which means 'is null' for Oracle, the condition will return 'false' or 'unknown', the latter being the same as the former in this case. So, again, why can it not be used in Oracle?

Comment: @Andriy: I think the problem is that in Oracle, `column <> ''` will be evaluated as  `column <> NULL` so `'some text' <> ''` will be evaluated as `'some text' <> NULL` = `NULL` (or `Unknown` as you call it). I guess one would like that to yield True and not Unknown.

Comment: @ypercube: I see now. All the time I was thinking only about `column` and missed the `''` as the right part of `<>`. Yes, it's all clear now, thank you! I mean, although you only *think* so, that's very much like what happens actually.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`NULLIF` is available on both Oracle ([doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm#i1001340)) and SQL Server ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562%28SQL.110%29.aspx)).  This expression should work:

```
NULLIF(column, '') IS NOT NULL
```

In both servers, if `column` is `NULL`, then the output of `NULLIF` will just pass the `NULL` value through.  On SQL Server, `'' = ''`, so the output of `NULLIF` will be `NULL`.  On Oracle, `''` is already `NULL`, so it gets passed through.

This is my test on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express:

```
WITH SampleData AS
    (SELECT 1 AS col1, NULL AS col2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, ''
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 'hello')
SELECT *
  FROM SampleData
 WHERE NULLIF(col2, '') IS NOT NULL;
```

And this is my test case on Oracle 10g XE:

```
WITH SampleData AS
    (SELECT 1 AS col1, NULL AS col2 FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, '' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 'hello' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM SampleData
 WHERE NULLIF(col2, '') IS NOT NULL;
```

Both return `3` as expected.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
CASE WHEN column = '' THEN NULL ELSE column END IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It works, but I prefer the NULLIF(column, '') IS NOT NULL solution as the column is only once and it is shorter.

Comment: Basically, the NULLIF version, expanded. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is to differentiate between the case when the empty string is equivalent to NULL and when it isn't:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN -- e.g., SQL Server this is true
              CASE WHEN col <> '' AND col IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
                   ELSE 'N'
              END
           WHEN COALESCE(col,NULL) IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' -- Not SS, e.g., Oracle
           ELSE 'N'
      END = 'Y';
```

If the first case is true then empty string is not the same as null, and we have to test for both string being not null and string not being the empty string. Otherwise, our task is easier because empty string and null evaluate the same.

Answer (score 0):

A try to shorten @DCookie's answer. I like his `( '' = '' )` test.

```
CASE WHEN ( '' = '' ) THEN ( column <> '' )
                      ELSE ( column = column )
END
```

Sadly, the above will not work. The next works in SQL-Server. I can't test in Oracle now:

```
CASE WHEN  '' = ''  THEN CASE WHEN column <> ''    THEN 1 ELSE NULL END 
                    ELSE CASE WHEN column = column THEN 1 ELSE NULL END 
END
```

which can be written also as:

```
    ( '' = ''    AND column <> '' )
 OR ( '' IS NULL AND column = column )
```

Comment: Does SQL Server allow you to directly compare to null? I can't test it, just asking. If not, your first test will fail when column is NULL. The second test will fail for sure on Oracle when column is NULL, because NULL = NULL is false.

Comment: @DCookie: Well, when column is NULL, we want it to fail, don't we?